# Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb on Mono/XSP

Tags: mono, system.web, xsp, owin, katana

I've managed to get Katana/OWIN running on Mono using the [HttpListener host](http://friism.com/running-owin-katana-apps-on-heroku).

I'm now experimenting with `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` on Mono and XSP4. I'm using the code found in the [this repo](https://github.com/friism/OWINSystemWebTest). It has a [`Startup` class](https://github.com/friism/OWINSystemWebTest/blob/master/KatanaSystemWebTest/Startup.cs):

```
using Owin;

namespace KatanaSystemWebTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseDiagnosticsPage();
        }
    }
}
```

In [web.config](https://github.com/friism/OWINSystemWebTest/blob/master/KatanaSystemWebTest/Web.config#L10), we define the `Configuration()` method as that one that starts the app:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="KatanaSystemWebTest.Startup.Configuration, KatanaSystemWebTest" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

This works great when debugging in Visual Studio, but not on Mono. I'm guessing it's some sort of assembly-loading hook that doesn't get fired. Any suggestions?

Here's an app running the code: http://peaceful-forest-6785.herokuapp.com/

[Full source code](https://github.com/friism/OWINSystemWebTest).

Comment: hi friism, have you got it work yet?  I'm trying to run the MVC WebApplication template with SignalR that uses Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (not self-host) and I couldn't even get the Startup.Configuration() loaded in Mono (Visual Studio 2013 works).  I wonder if you have got it work or not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I get this to work by telling XSP which is the Startup class and method via *assembly attribute*:

```
using Owin;
﻿using Microsoft.Owin; // <--- this is new
﻿
// this is new:
﻿[assembly: OwinStartup (typeof (KatanaSystemWebTest.Startup), "Configuration")]

namespace KatanaSystemWebTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseDiagnosticsPage();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also created a pull pull request with this fix in the repo.